# How to find mid of two time values in php?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have two time values like below:

$a = 22:15

$b = 28:50

28:50 would imply 04:50 am

How do I find out mid of these two time values? In simple maths, it would be like below:

$c = ($b-$a) / 2

*(below line edited)
echo $c + $a;

Of course it's not that simple, I did Google and searched everywhere but in vain.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Are these strings or timestamps?

Comment: convert them to minutes or second, perform the simple math average, and convert back to the format you need.

Comment: did you solve problem?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes mate, right now these are string values. another mate suggested that I convert these to timestamp and do simple math calc.

Answer (score 1):

I would STRONGLY recommend you working with [timestamps](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).
Then you could simply do the following:

```
// Assuming $b and $a as timestamps
$c = ($b-$a)/2;
echo date('H:i', $c);
```

Comment: so, you mean, I add date value to time, convert that to unix-timestamps, and then do that calc, right?  I'll try that mate, thanks!

Comment: It would be best to omit time-strings and use timestamps instead whenever you can. This might help you: [php datetime reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).

Answer (score 0):

I did not code anything at all during past 5 years, but, I'm glad that I was able to code this with the help of you guys.. here below is the code I was looking for:

```
<?
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Date-Time 1: <input type="text" name="time1"><br>
Date-Time 2: <input type="text" name="time2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>


<?

if ( !empty($_POST) )
{

$time1 = $_POST["time1"];
$time2 = $_POST["time2"];

// echo $time1 . "<br>";

$utime1 = strtotime($time1);
$utime2 = strtotime($time2);

$temp = $utime2 - $utime1;
$temp = $temp/2;

$MidTime = $utime1 + $temp;


echo "Time 1: " . $time1 . "<br>";
echo "Time 2: " . $time2 . "<br><br>";

echo "U-Time 1: " . $utime1 . "<br>";
echo "U-Time 2: " . $utime2 . "<br><br>";

echo "UTime-2  minus UTime-1 in Unix: " . $temp . "<br><br>";


echo "Mid Time: " . gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s ", $MidTime);

}


?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXx3b.png)